# Limit methods exposed in c# class to api users

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, frameworks

I have a base class Called usermanager.
Methods in UserManager

```
->CreateUser
->DeleteUser
->GetUser
```

I have two types of api Users

```
->Framework Delelopers who should have access to CreateUser , Delete User method
->Application developer who have access to GetUser only
```

How I can restrict message exposed by UserManager to different api users

Please suggest any oops concepts or way to organize my class or hide method so  that each user can access limited set of methods.

Method createuser and deleteuser should be accessible to fraemwork delevelopers

and only getUser method should be avaiabe to application developers.

Comment: There are many different ways to accomplish this. From the basic: check user has rights to this method manually ... to the (what we seem to opt for at my workplace) more advanced interceptors that validate the method invocation. My point is that you're likely to get varying answers to this question. Can you narrow it a bit?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much of your application works, but we a custom membership provider and custom principal which implements IPrincipal and then we use roles.

So in this case the roles would be something like 'FRAMEWORK_DEV' and 'APP_DEV'

and use the authorize attr on the classes

for example:

```
[Authorize("FRAMEWORK_DEV")]
[HttpGet, Route("")]
public void CreateUser() 
{
    /* Do Stuff */     
}
```

Take a look at this answer which might help

[Sample Code for Creating Custom Membership Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263537/sample-code-for-creating-custom-membership-provider)